# I just want to download this URL...but it is giving me an error! ...unicode.. (Python)

Tags: python, http, unicode, urllib2, encode

```
theurl = 'http://bit.ly/6IcCtf/'
urlReq = urllib2.Request(theurl)
urlReq.add_header('User-Agent',random.choice(agents))
urlResponse = urllib2.urlopen(urlReq)
htmlSource = urlResponse.read()
if unicode == 1:
    #print urlResponse.headers['content-type']
    #encoding=urlResponse.headers['content-type'].split('charset=')[-1]
    #htmlSource = unicode(htmlSource, encoding)
    htmlSource =  htmlSource.encode('utf8')
return htmlSource
```

**Please take a look at the unicode portion.  I've tried those two options...but doesn't work.**

```
htmlSource =  htmlSource.encode('utf8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 370747: ordinal not in range(128)
```

and also this when I try the longer method of encoding...

```
_mysql_exceptions.Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xE7\xB9\x81\xE9\xAB\x94...' for column 'html' at row 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your html data is a string that comes from the internet **already encoded** with some encoding. Before encoding it to `utf-8`, you **must decode it first**.

Python is ***implicity*** trying to decode it (That's why you get a `UnicodeDecodeError` not `UnicodeEncodeError`).

You can solve the problem by *explicity decoding your bytestring* (using the appropriate encoding) **before** trying to reencode it to `utf-8`.

Example:

```
utf8encoded = htmlSource.decode('some_encoding').encode('utf-8')
```

Use the correct encoding the page was encoded in first place, instead of `'some_encoding'`.

You **have** to know which encoding a string is using before you can decode it.

Answer (score 3):

Not decode? `htmlSource =  htmlSource.decode('utf8')`

decode mean "decode htmlSource from utf8 encoding"

encode mean "encode htmlSource to utf8 encoding"

since you are extracting the existing data (crawling from website), you need to decode it, and when you insert to mysql, you may need to encode as utf8 according to your mysql db/table/fields collations.

Comment: I want to encode it so that I can insert it into the database

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to *decode* Utf8, not *encode* it:

```
htmlSource =  htmlSource.decode('utf8')
```